# ngTable tooltip (title attribute) does not show data values

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

In this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8abiLrqa6hAoFSySgaLT?p=preview) I have an ngTable with two columns. When I hover over the data, the tooltip shows the column name instead of the value. This is because the `title` attribute of `td` is set with the column name. How to fix it to show the actual value?

HTML

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="u in data">
                <td title="u.uid">{{ u.uid }}</td>
                <td title="u.ugr">{{ u.ugr }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTable']);
app.controller('myCtl', function($scope,NgTableParams) {

      $scope.data = [ 
        { uid: 'User 1',ugr: 'Group 1'},
        { uid: 'User 2', ugr: 'Group 2'}
      ];

      $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({dataset: $scope.data});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use on your `td` this:

```
<td ng-attr-title="{{u.uid}}">{{ u.uid }}</td>
<td ng-attr-title="{{u.ugr}}">{{ u.ugr }}</td>
```